# Remapping the way that I switch betweens spaces

Tags: keyboard, spaces

I'm a former Linux user who just switched to a new mbp and I've got a spaces question.

On my linux box I could remap the keys that would move left and right between virtual desktops (spaces).

Is there a way to remap the keyboard in OSX?  Specificlly I'd like to be able to move to the space on the left of the current one with  `CMD + H` and move to the space to the right of me with `CMD + L`.

How can I do this?

Thank you,

Joe

Comment: possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3880/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-to-change-active-spaces-desktop

Answer (score 1):

Apple > System Preferences > Expose&Spaces / Spaces Bottom half of the window
Apple > System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts

While it IS possible, it's not suggested. You might be a lil hard pressed to find a solution. Go for a 3 finger combo?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into the following:

- [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/)
- [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/)
- This [Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/binding-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-shut-down)
- This [Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5619/keyboard-shortcut-for-toggling-between-fn-and-f-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Nooo! You don't reassign the <kbd>⌘</kbd>-keys on a Mac. Many of their assignments were declared as sacred ages ago.

<kbd>⌘H</kbd> is used to hide an application — something very useful in a multiple document interface. <kbd>⌘L</kbd> is one of the few that don't have a reserved function. ([AHIG Keyboard Shortcuts Quick Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/XHIGKeyboardShortcuts/XHIGKeyboardShortcuts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002725-CHDIGFBH).) Still, it's used commonly for actions like focusing the location bar in the browser.

As for the actual question, [HyperSpaces](https://hyperspacesapp.com) has customizable shortcuts. It also has *Send window to next / previous space*, which is missing from normal Spaces.

Comment: It is easy to move windows between spaces. Click and hold the title bar and either press the key combo to change spaces, or drag the window to the edge of the screen and hold it there for a little bit.

Comment: I didn't know about using the shortcuts while dragging the window. Still, having a dedicated shortcut is even more convenient.